# Calculate "camera" projection limit points

Tags: math, opengl, graphics, opengl-compat

I need to calculate the eight points which define the limits of a orthographic perspective. I am using OpenGL deprecated functions:

```py
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        # self.zoom is a integer used for zooming in and out the camera
        # The near and far values are hardcoded to +-5000
        glOrtho(self.zoom, -self.zoom, -self.zoom, self.zoom, -5000, 5000)
        up = 1
        if self.theta == 360:
            up = -1
        # self.x self.y self.z are the coords of the looked point
        # self.deviation_x/y/z are the coords of the observer
        # There is a strange bug, when self.theta = 360 the camera flips, it gets fixed flipping again the camera
        gluLookAt(self.x, self.y, self.z, self.deviation_x, self.deviation_y, self.deviation_z, 0, up, 0)

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        # Drawing stuff
```

I need to get the coordinates of the following points:

[image: ortho perspective]

Comment: Multiply the combined (projection * modelview) matrix by `(±1, ±1, ±1)` to get the 8 points?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat how can I do that? Using `glGetFloat(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX)`? I get this: [[-4.7140452e-03 -3.3333332e-03 -9.9999997e-05  0.0000000e+00]
 [ 0.0000000e+00  4.7140452e-03 -1.4142135e-04  0.0000000e+00]
 [ 4.7140452e-03 -3.3333332e-03 -9.9999997e-05  0.0000000e+00]
 [ 0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  1.9999999e-04  1.0000000e+00]]

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you forgot taking the inverse

Comment: @PepeElMago33 you query both matrices, and just do the math.

Comment: @derhass how can I query both matrices?

Comment: the one is `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX`, the other `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX`